# Java Regex not working as desired

Tags: java, regex, string

I created this regex, but somehow it only detects the first part 
of the regex not the last part. I would like to know what is going on?

Here's the code:

```
String m = -2√3254i/18.5
String regex = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i\\/\\d+(\\.\\d*)?"
```

I have tried many different ways, such as:

```
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i+\\/+\\d+(\\.\\d*)?
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i/\\d+(\\.\\d*)?
-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i\\(\\/\\d+(\\.\\d*))?
```

none of them work.

the output is always

```
-2√3254
```

Any suggestions,

thank you

Comment: what output you expect to get?

Comment: what did you mean by `but somehow it only detects the first part of the regex not the last part` ?

Comment: I expect to get the whole string. Well it only gives me back -2√3254 not the entire string, which is what I expect. @YCF_L

Comment: is that all your code? what is the inputs?

Comment: the input is the string m. The regex should detect the entire string. @YCF_L

Comment: `"-2√3254i/18.5".matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i\\/\\d+(\\.\\d*)?")` return `true` mean your regex is correct for this input!!

Comment: with the method matches it works, but I need it to work with a matcher object so I can use matcherobject.find() method @YCF_L

Comment: did you mean `String m = "-2√3254i/18.5";
String regex = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i+\\/+\\d+(\\.\\d*)?";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(m);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}` ?

Comment: yes. that is what I mean @YCF_L

Comment: It is weird that it works with matches method not with find() method. I wonder why?

Comment: no it work with me try to copy past my code and you will see

Comment: yes I see that it works, the problem is that my regex is really composed of many regexes into one. I separate them with "|" symbol . Maybe one of the other regexes that makes up my regex got in the way of matching the string. I probably should use the matches method instead. @YCF_L

Comment: analyse your problem step by step, not me who down-vote your question ok :) good luck

Comment: I know exactly what happened. I will post the solution shortly. Can you remove the down vote. @YCF_L

Comment: no it is not me who down-vote your question ok here my up-vote!

Comment: I just posted my answer @YCF_L

Answer (score 1):

Okay so my regex is actually composed of many regexes:

```
String regex = "a regex | another regex | -?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\i" 
              + "|another regex | -?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?\\√\\d+(\\.\\d*)?i\\/\\d+ (\\.\\d*)?
```

The problem happens between both regexes shown. The ***first*** symbolical regex is picked up by the matcher *first*, but I really intended for the ***second*** symbolical regex to pick up my `String m = "-2√32454i/18.5"`

It seems the matcher exits matching when one of the boolean conditions is met. 
All I had to do was rearrange the order of my regexes which make up my regex.